# Why can't I see the ad?

Tags: android, admob

I tried to display an ad on top of a custom view but somehow I can't see it.

```
layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    view = new GameView(this);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    layout.addView(view);
    layout.addView(adView, 640, 100);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("id").build());

    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've replaced the `setAdUnitId()` with the correct ID, right?

Comment: Yes I just replayed it for the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the way you're adding `View`s to the `LinearLayout`. The `adView` seems ok, but my bet is there's something with the `GameView` class that makes it not show up.

I'd recommend defining the `AdView` containing `LinearLayout` in the layout file instead of declaring a new `LinearLayout` programmatically, and add the `View` afterwards like you're doing right now. The following code is the one I use and it works, that's why I assume this is a layout problem.

```
final LinearLayout adLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_ad_containing_linearlayout);

final AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId("your-id");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

adLayout.addView(adView);

final AdRequest.Builder adReq = new AdRequest.Builder();
adReq.addTestDevice("...");

final AdRequest adRequest = adReq.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the LinearLayout. 
If you want to display the ad on top of the GameView, you should use FrameLayout simply like below

```
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    view = new GameView(this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);

    adView.setAdUnitId("id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    layout.addView(view);
    layout.addView(adView, 640, 100);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("id").build());
```

Comment: You should import LayoutParams from FrameLayout. Look at the imports of your java file and delete LayoutParams from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you set your 'parent' layout's orientation as Horizontal. Try set it as Vertical.

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

And make sure your custom view GameView doesn't have the layout height as MATCH_PARENT, because add it first, and if it's height is set to fill the parent the view below it won't be visible.